# Dishwasher leaking from bottom

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

I have a Electrolux ESL 4114.

In the last couple of months I’ve noticed a weird smell out of it.

Yesterday I have had a look at it and when turning it upside down a lot of very dirty water leaked. The base was very wet and full of mould.
After inspecting it, I came to the conclusion that it leaks through the drain — in the same unit that the outlet hose is attached.

In the attached picture there seems to be a rubber hose between the main drain and the pump that isn’t leaking. I have tried to replace the clip, but it didn’t work out.

What do you guys think would be best to seal that hose?

[image]

(The silver clip is the one I’ve tried to fit, but I had the same issue after as well — the other one is the one that was there previously).

Answer (score 2):

The screw type clamps are very reliable.

It looks as if the gold spring clamp is in the middle of the hose.  It may be compressing the hose there and causing the ends to "bell out".  That may be the reason for the leak.  Try moving the spring clamp closer to the end of the hose.